# Postfix can send mails to all domains except gmail

Tags: email, postfix, configuration, gmail

I'm encountering a strange issue with my postfix server. I can send and receive emails just fine, except gmail ones. Whenever I send a mail to e.g. someone@gmail.com, it returns

```
I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered [...]

                   The mail system

<someone@gmail.com>: user unknown
```

and this is what I get in the mail.log

```
15:32 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<kontakt@minzkraut.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.120.177.241, lip=37.120.177.241, mpid=20955, TLS, session=<jaW3/4ZRAqsleLHx>
15:32 postfix/smtpd[20956]: connect from v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de[37.120.177.241]
15:32 postfix/smtpd[20956]: 4B34140DE2: client=v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de[37.120.177.241], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=kontakt@minzkraut.com
15:32 postfix/cleanup[20961]: 4B34140DE2: message-id=<592801bf80ad3c84cefbba9d68947b6a@minzkraut.com>
15:32 postfix/qmgr[17940]: 4B34140DE2: from=<kontakt@minzkraut.com>, size=1123, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
15:32 postfix/smtpd[20956]: disconnect from v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de[37.120.177.241]
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:44313 to port 783, fd 5
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: setuid to vmail succeeded
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: creating default_prefs: /home/vmail/.spamassassin/user_prefs
15:32 spamd[17176]: config: cannot create user preferences file /home/vmail/.spamassassin/user_prefs: No such file or directory
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: failed to create readable default_prefs: /home/vmail/.spamassassin/user_prefs
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: processing message <592801bf80ad3c84cefbba9d68947b6a@minzkraut.com> for vmail:2000
15:32 spamd[17176]: plugin: eval failed: bayes: (in learn) locker: safe_lock: cannot create tmp lockfile /home/vmail/.spamassassin/bayes.lock.v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de.17176 for /home/vmail/.spamassassin/bayes.lock: No such file or directory
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: clean message (0.0/4.5) for vmail:2000 in 0.0 seconds, 1199 bytes.
15:32 spamd[17176]: spamd: result: . 0 - scantime=0.0,size=1199,user=vmail,uid=2000,required_score=4.5,rhost=localhost,raddr=::1,rport=44313,mid=<592801bf80ad3c84cefbba9d68947b6a@minzkraut.com>,autolearn=unavailable autolearn_force=no
15:32 postfix/pipe[20963]: 4B34140DE2: to=<someone@gmail.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.14, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.07, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)
15:32 postfix/cleanup[20961]: 6C497422EF: message-id=<20170609133221.6C497422EF@v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de>
15:32 postfix/bounce[20966]: 4B34140DE2: sender non-delivery notification: 6C497422EF
15:32 postfix/qmgr[17940]: 6C497422EF: from=<>, size=3001, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
15:32 dovecot: imap(kontakt@minzkraut.com): Logged out in=1056 out=1358
15:32 postfix/qmgr[17940]: 4B34140DE2: removed
15:32 dovecot: lda(kontakt@minzkraut.com): sieve: msgid=<20170609133221.6C497422EF@v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
15:32 postfix/pipe[20967]: 6C497422EF: to=<kontakt@minzkraut.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.08, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
15:32 postfix/qmgr[17940]: 6C497422EF: removed
15:32 spamd[17175]: prefork: child states: II
15:32 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<kontakt@minzkraut.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.120.177.241, lip=37.120.177.241, mpid=20970, TLS, session=<PxS9/4ZRCqsleLHx>
15:32 dovecot: imap(kontakt@minzkraut.com): Logged out in=90 out=937
```

I already grepped for "Gmail" in my dovecot and postfix configs, but there was nothing.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: `postconf -n`

```
alias_maps = $alias_database
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_transport = local
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 52428800
mydomain = v22017054597548976.hotsrv.de
myhostname = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_permissions.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/apache2/certs/
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/apache2/certs/
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

EDIT2: Here is the master.cf of postfix, also note that I can send to gmail just fine using `mail` or `sendmail`

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
# Dovecot LDA
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe
    flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

Comment: Show postconf -n

Comment: @AlexD added it to the question

Comment: Your log has `relay=spamassassin` but your configuration doesn't mention it anywhere. Could you add content of `master.cf`?

Comment: You're also loading configuration from the mysql database in the virtual_alias_maps, vnirtual_mailbox_domains, virtual_mailbox_maps (I'd guess one of those might be matching gmail) and I'd bet a line in your master.cf is shoving it off to spamassassin listening on port 783 (which is crashing beacuse there's no /home/vmail)

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be using SMTP port `25` for both incoming and outgoing mail. Because you have

```
smtp         inet  n    -   -   -   -   smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin

spamassassin unix  -    n   n   -   -   pipe
    flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

this will cause also all outgoing mail to go through Spamassassin, which is the one that gives you the error `dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)` after `spamd[17176]: plugin: eval failed:`.

This is not the only problem with this configuration:

- Users seem to authenticate to SMTP with plain text passwords (`sasl_method=PLAIN)` since you are missing `smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt`. Extremely insecure and risky!
- Using port `25` for connections other than from *Message Transfer Agents* (MTAs) may cause problems to your clients since, from [RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409) Introduction:

> For example, due to the prevalence of machines that have worms, viruses, or other malicious software that generate large amounts of spam, many sites now prohibit outbound traffic on the standard SMTP port (port 25), funneling all mail submissions through submission servers.

The [RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409) is the specification for *Message Submission for Mail* and **you haven't configured your Postfix properly to act as a *Message Submission Agent* (MSA)**. Doing this will, on the side, fix your problem that probably only seems to be related to Gmail, but is actually wider.

Basically you usually enable submission on port `587` by uncommenting these `master.cf` lines:

```
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Along with this, you should remove the occurrences of `permit_sasl_authenticated` from `main.cf`.

This might not be all you need to do. It seems like Dovecot you are using for SASL has better tutorial for using Postfix submission than Postfix's own [SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html). From [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL):

> **Using SASL with Postfix submission port**
>
> When Dovecot is used as the authentication backend for Postfix it is
> good practice to use a dedicated submission port for the MUAs (TCP
> `587`). Not only can you specify individual parameters in `master.cf`
> overriding the global ones but you will not run into internet mail
> rejection while the Dovecot Auth Mechanism is unavailable.
>
> In this
> example Postfix is configured to accept TLS encrypted sessions only,
> along with several other sanity checks:
>
> - Verification of alias ownership via Login Maps
> - Domainname and recipient plausibility
>
> `master.cf`
>
> ```
> submission inet n - n - - smtpd
>   -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
>   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
>   -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
>   -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
>   -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
>   -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
>   -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
>   -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
>   -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
>   -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
> ```